# Seaborn heatmap top and bottom row are partially truncated

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to make a heatmap out of a dataframe, but the size of the blocks in the first and last row are not as equal as the blocks in the other rows. How can I fix this problem?

P.S. I am using python3 and seaborn library to produce the heatmap.

[image]

Comment: Notice that in both directions, the ticks are in the middle of the blocks, but your y-axis starts and ends on a full tick instead of a half tick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [issue](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1773) has been raised and closed on the Seaborn github. The solution found there by [ResidentMario](https://github.com/ResidentMario) & [MaozGelbart](https://github.com/MaozGelbart) was:

> This was a matplotlib regression introduced in 3.1.1 which has been fixed in 3.1.2 (still forthcoming). For now the fix is to downgrade matplotlib to a prior version.

And later,

> Matplotlib 3.1.2 has been released (also available for conda users through conda-forge using conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib=3.1.2). This fixes the issue.

Comment: upgrading MatLibPlot worked, thank you